# Download a pdf rendered by pdf.js

Tags: pdf, html, javascript

My tution gives out notes of their classes on their website, but they make them undownloadable.
They are rendered in the browser with mozila's pdf.js library, and the 'download' button is hidden.

I found [this](https://superuser.com/a/1365711/1672119) answer here, but I couldn't find `display: none` in that button field. I also tried doing what the first comment of the same answer suggested, but `document.getElementById('download').click()` showed `undefined`

Comment: Link to an example? …or is it all paywalled?

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't send a link because you need an account and password to login on my tution site

Comment: If you can send the PDF.js version to a physical printer, perhaps you could print to a new PDF instead?

Comment: @Anaksunaman both the print and download buttons are hidden

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you inspect element and paste the HTML code corresponding to the pdf.js canvas into a pastebin so we know what we're dealing with.